Movie about a group of monster disguised as human attacking a building
I remember watch this movie around 10 years ago. It's in color and subbed to my country language (Malaysia). I don't know the original language of this movie because I was a teen back then. I also did not know the release year of this movie, but judging by some scene, it maybe from early to mid 2000's. It's not animated, but I'm sure it involved some CGI.
These are some detail I vaguely remember:  

A group of monster/alien attacking a building (I believe it's a university building/school)
There were at least 4 monsters attacking the building.
One monster's true form is a man-eating creature with long hair and shining eyes. It attacks and eats soldiers that tried to infiltrate the building
One monster's true form is a tentacle featured creature. I remember a scene in which it was pressed to a wall by some kind of machine but it survived.
One monster's true form is a creature that looks like Tangela from Pokemon with sharp teeth and strong power. It may create a hole in a stone wall.
The protagonist is a teenage boy and has a dog as a pet.


Is this animated?

@Paulie_D no. But I'm sure it's involved some CGI.

Some of it sounds like The Faculty [esp. a tentacle creature "pressed to a wall by some kind of machine", that's how it ends (though the creature doesn't survive)], but IIRC there was only one type of alien there.

@Walt I've watched The Faculty and it's not the one I'm looking for.
